# How to display Youtube 10 Trending Video with video id?

Tags: php, api, video, youtube, trending

please help how to display youtube 10 trending video with video ID.

i using this code but not show video id help. but correctly show trending video.

```
function CURL($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en";
    $header[] = "User-Agent: $uaa";
    $header[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
    $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate";
    $header[] = "Content-Encoding: gzip";
    $header[] = "Content-Encoding: deflate";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $load = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $load;

     return file_get_contents($url);
}

$grab = CURL('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyAjMsVN8Q-sUQHnc9qv7D9cA0X0xhcqrec&part=id,snippetcontentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=US&maxResults=10&type=video');

$json = json_decode($grab);

foreach ($json->items as $video)
{
echo $video->id->videoId;
echo $video->snippet->title;
echo $video->snippet->description;
echo $video->snippet->channelTitle;
echo $video->snippet->channelId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource you can able to use just $video->id so just change echo $video->id->videoID to $video->id